# Programa que faça toda a tabuada entre dois numeros que eu digitar

Tags: portugol

ex 2 4 o programa tem que fazer a tabuada do dois do 3 e do quatro em Portugol

```
/*mostra toda a tabuada entre dois numeros digitados
name will
data 22/04/2019*/
programa
{

    funcao inicio()
    {
        inteiro n1,n2,aux,contador=0,total
        escreva("Informe o primeiro numero")
        leia(n1)
        escreva("Informe o segundo numero")
        leia(n2)
        se(n2<n1){
            aux=n2
            n2=n1
            n1=aux
        }
        enquanto(n2>=n1){
            enquanto ( contador<= 10 )  {
                total=n1*contador
                escreva(n1,"x",contador,"=",total,"\n")
                contador=contador+1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O que você ja tentou fazer?

Comment: Sugiro que explique sua dificuldade, até onde chegou, etc. Senão vai parecer que vc só quer que alguém faça sua lição de casa.

Comment: ja reformulei a pergunta e coloquei o que eu ja fiz ja consegui fazer com que ele mostre a tabuada mas não de todos os numeros entre o primeiro numero que eu digitei e o segundo

Comment: ele so faz a primeira tabuada do primeiro numero no caso n1 e ignora n2

Comment: Ele trava quando chega na parte do enquanto contador < =10 ele considera que termino mas fica faltando as outras tabuadas e não estou conseguindo resolver

Answer (score 0):

Faltou incrementar o valor de `n1` ao finalizar a tabuada.
E vai precisar zerar o `contador` ao iniciar a tabuada do número seguinte.